# How to connect On-Premises Active Directory from Azure Automation account(Runbook)

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-automation

**How to connect On-Premises Active Directory server from  Azure Automation Account (Runbook)**, using powershell to create users on **AD** and to the specific OU, adding users to the group. Here the group will be array. THanks in Advance.

Comment: You can surely refer to the link given in here for this purpose on the correct steps/procedure to connect to on-premises active directory from Azure automation : -https://practical365.com/how-to-manage-on-premises-infrastructure-using-azure-automation-hybrid-worker/